# How to keep a ftp server in sync with mac folder

Tags: mac, sync, ftp

So I have a folder on my mac that I want to be synced with my ftp server.
So far all the solutions i have found were for windows only. Are there any for mac?

Answer (score 1):

[Syncovery](https://www.syncovery.com/)

Professional version supports FTP >  [Matrix](https://www.syncovery.com/matrix/)

> Back up your data and synchronize PCs, **Macs**, servers, notebooks, and
> online storage space. You can set up as many different jobs as you
> need and run them manually or using the scheduler. Syncovery works
> with local hard drives, network drives and any other mounted volumes.
>
> In addition, it comes with **support for FTP**, SSH, HTTP, WebDAV, Amazon
> S3, and Google Docs. You can use ZIP compression and data encryption.
> On Windows, the scheduler can run as a service – without users having
> to log on. There are powerful synchronization modes, including
> Standard Copying, Exact Mirror, and SmartTracking.

Comment: seems quite pricey, but I'll check it out.

Comment: I checked it out and it works fine, but it's a bit slow on detecting changes and whenever I am trying to make a small tweak, it can take me up to 10 minutes instead of the needed 1 minute that it should because of waiting game played inbetween edits.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Fetch, Interarchy, and Yummy over the years, in that order, with [Yummy](http://www.yummysoftware.com/) being my current favorite FTP/sync tool.  At $15, it's a lot cheaper than Matrix, but does a TON of stuff.

There is also FileZilla as a decent free tool too.

Comment: Yummy is a 32-bit app and will not work with MacOS Catalina (fall 2019)